# Can I use the hidden methods in WifiP2pManager?

Tags: android, android-wifi, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I noticed that Settings uses some methods and fields in WifiP2pManager that I'm not able to access, like `deletePersistentGroup()`.

```
    ...
    mWifiP2pManager.deletePersistentGroup(mChannel, 
    mSelectedGroup.getNetworkId(),
        new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
    public void onSuccess() {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, " delete group success");
    }
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, " delete group fail " + reason);
    }
});
```

There is also an Intent `WIFI_P2P_PERSISTENT_GROUPS_CHANGED_ACTION` that I'm not able to access. Is there any way I could use this like settings does?

Link to the settings file: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pSettings.java